# Elements do not resize after orientation change in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, resize, reload

I know this is an old question, but after trying all the proposed methods, nothing seems fit.

Basically, I built this webpage, it looks fine when just loaded with a mobile device, but after screen rotation the size stays the same, (which it should not!)

### 1:

The first method I tried is adding the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

But apparently this does not work

### 2:

Then I tried window.location.reload
This works! Just perfect. But it basically reloaded the whole page, and all the previous setting will be reset to the default, this is not what I want!

### 3:

I see someone suggesting writing two sets of css, one for landscape and one for portrait. However, this is a lot of work right?
And, in my css I did not set a lot of explicit height and width anyway. Usually it's default, and sometimes in percentage. Is this a problem?

## #

It will be great if someone explain a little what actually happens when the screen rotate? Why elements are not resized properly? And on contrary, why they will be resized properly if a reload event is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which mobile browser you're testing on; some mobile browsers, notably IE10, [don't report a change in screen size](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html#t00) when the orientation changes. However, as you found out the browser does recalculate the screen size when the page is refreshed.

If you can tell us about the browser, maybe we can help more?